# Different where values in field

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi i am trying to build a mysql query,

I have `products` table and my focus fields are `company_id` and `amount`

I want to select **amount grater than 0** but must be include **company_id is 1** ( there are have a lot of `company_id` )

when i include **WHERE amount > 0** condition, it is hiding `company_id = 1`  rows

How can i select all companies with `amount > 0` but only skip `company_id = 1` amounts

I have tried

```
SELECT company_id, amount from products WHERE (CASE products.company_id
        WHEN 1 THEN products.amount > 0 ELSE 1 END)
```

Answer (score 2):

From what you mention it seems that `company_id = 1` does not have rows with `amount > 0`, but you want it in the results:

```
SELECT company_id, amount from products 
WHERE company_id = 1 OR amount > 0
```

Comment: @MertDeniz if this answer solved your problem consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark at the left.

Comment: I tried marking it correct, but was unable to `:-)`